# How to move a form programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in this C# thing and need your help

Currently I have a form with 4 buttons on a form (Up,Down,Left,Right)

I would like to move the form 10 pixels to the direction that was pressed.

Comment: You are also new to this SO thing.  Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: ←:`this.Left -= 10;` , →:`this.Left += 10;` and the same for `Top`.

Comment: See the `Location` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set them individually, use the form's Left (X) or Top (Y) sub property. **Do not** try to implicitly set the X and Y coordinates of the Point structure that represents the form's location, because this contains a copy of the form's coordinates.

To change form position programmatic by increments, increase or decrease X and Y coordinates

- Left = X
- Top = Y

### Example button events:

```
private void UpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{
    this.Top -= 10;
}

private void DownButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Top += 10;
}

private void RightButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Left += 10;
}

private void LeftButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Left -= 10;
}
```

> To clarify e.g. `this.Top -= 10;` is short for `this.Top = this.Top - 10;`

### Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Move form to the right:

```
private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     form.Location = new Point(form.Location.X + 10, form.Location.Y);
}
```

Move form to the left:

```
private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     form.Location = new Point(form.Location.X - 10, form.Location.Y);
}
```

Move form up:

```
private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     form.Location = new Point(form.Location.X, form.Location.Y - 10);
}
```

Move form down:

```
private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     form.Location = new Point(form.Location.X, form.Location.Y + 10);
}
```

Edit:
If by form you mean the main window, just replace every "form" in my code with "this".

Comment: Thank you for that great answer Jim
But isnt "this" refer to the button ?